# How to get a variable from slot?

Tags: qt, blackberry-10, signals-slots

can i use a slot with return ?
for example :

```
QObject::connect(sender, SIGNAL(finished()), receiver, SLOT(onprocessFinished()));
```

and the pnprocessFinished return a QString that be used later
that is possible? if yes how it must be done ?

Comment: That's a prime example for looking into the documentation. There exist many slots to get certain values upon specific "events"; it depends primarily on what QObject-derivation you talk about. That is, your question is not well-researched and, as is, too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slot can return a value, but the signal has to return the same type and it works for *direct connection*. You will get the returned value when you call `emit`:

```
void A::foo() {
    connect( this, SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT( mySlot() ) );
    int var = emit mySignal(); // int mySignal()
    qDebug() << var; // will print 12
}

int A::mySlot() {
    return 12;
}
```

But, I don't think that is useful...

Comment: There is a very good answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842124/can-qt-signals-return-a-value but one thing not addressed is cross thread signaling. Expecting a return value from a SIGNAL-SLOT connection assumes implementation details are function call semantics. In Cascades SIGNALS often cross threads and are actioned asynchronously. The fact that is works sounds like an artifact of the MOC compiler not a feature of the environment.